# Google Cast plugin for Unity can't stream Video clip

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, video, plugins, google-cast

I'm trying to play a Video inside Unity, and stream it to Google Cast.
[Google provides a plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/50168) that enables the connection to a Cast device, and it works fine once a correct Cast App ID is given.

Recently Unity provided a component 'VideoPlayer' that enables video playback inside a mobile device. And I tried to use both of them to stream video content on the Cast device. But when I play the video, the app stops responding with a signal 'SIGABRT' at

`reinterpret_cast<PInvokeFunc>(_native_GCKUnityRenderRemoteDisplay)();`

I also tried to play the video using AVPro plugin but the same issue appeared.

The plugin works just fine without a video, and the last update of the plugin is Apr 2016 so I think the plugin has some issue with the Unity's latest VideoPlayer component.

Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no plans to update the Google Cast Unity plugin.

Comment: Oh... sorry to hear that. Thanks for the reply though.